# Where is this Google Meet backdrop?

Tags: identify-this, where-on-earth, landscape

Apparently it's called "Home Office by the Bay", and a colleague and I are wondering where it's taken (or if it's AI generated).

[image]

Comment: I believe it's somewhere in Northern Norway, but I might be confused with a similarly-looking cabin in a similarly-looking location.  Not quite [panoramahyttene](https://panoramahyttene.no/english) (which are in southern Norway), but I recall seeing cabins like this at the [Helgeland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helgeland) coast.  If it's AI-generated, then it's probably trained with images from Norway :) (not great for home office on a sunny day!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google reverse image search shows that a video of this backdrop was posted by Brick Visual to their [facebook page](https://m.facebook.com/BrickVisual/videos/) under the title "Glamping". Brick Visual says on their ["about us" page](https://web.archive.org/web/20240309151830/https://brickvisual.com/about/).

> Brick is an international creative production studio that translates great ideas into high-end visual solutions.

So it seems like, the backdrop is digitally generated and not a real place. It's visually similar to this [glass lodge in Iceland](https://panoramaglasslodge.com/) though:

[image]

(Source: https://panoramaglasslodge.com/)

Comment: How do we know it's Google using Brick's image, and not the other way around?

Comment: @lambshaanxy “_Following up on our previous collaboration with Google Workspace, delivering a series of virtual backgrounds for conversations on Google Meet_…”

Comment: Interesting that Google has flipped it horizontally. Random